# Image not updating through AJAX PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Following code is from a login page. I want to update the image of user when user fill username onkeyup. Image path is to get through PHP. Script code is given below:

```
function showUserPic(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

//              document.getElementById("img").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                x = document.getElementById("img");
                x.src = 'users/'+xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

HTML Code is given below:

```
<input type="text" class="inputLabel1" style="margin:5px;" name="userText" onkeyup="showUserPic(this.value)" />
```

PHP file code is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php
      $user = intval($_GET['q']);
      $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pharmacy");

      if (!$conn) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }

      $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user';";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      $userdata = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

      mysqli_close($conn);

      echo $userdata['image'];
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check what answer are you getting back from the server ?

Comment: You want just the image path but you are supplying a bunch of HTML

Comment: Do you mind to use jquery ajax other than the pure ajax? It will be easier to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dan-klasson stated - you need to return from server only image path. Your HTML and JS can stay AS-IS, but you need to change your PHP markup to just:

```
<?php
  $user = intval($_GET['q']);

  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pharmacy");
  if (!$conn) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

  $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user';";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  $userdata = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  mysqli_close($conn);

  echo $userdata['image'];
?>
```

Your actual code are returning:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    example_image.jpg
  </body>
</html>
```

and your script are inserting all of this into your image tag, so it will be:

```
<img src="users/%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chtml%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20example_image.jpg%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fhtml%3E"/>
```

It's probably not what you want :) Just change your PHP code.

**EDIT:**
One additional mistake in your code is that you have intval on your request parameter (which tries to be username):

```
$user = intval($_GET['q']);
```

Change it to:

```
$user = $_GET['q'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just used:echo $userdata['image']; how it is returning this much lag? I am new to AJAX. Please explain..

Comment: Probably AJAX is not the case. Try to manually go to this URL: getuser.php?q=your_query and see how long it takes to load. It can depend on DB optimalization (index on username column would be great).

Answer (score 1):

First of all a suggestion: `$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user';";`is better to be `$query = "SELECT image FROM users WHERE username = '$user';";` since there is no need to return all the columns from the table.

Then you should consider turning to PDO instead of deprecated mysql and mysqli extentions.

Then your issue is here:

```
$userdata = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
mysqli_close($conn);

echo $userdata['image'];
```

$userdata is an array. So you can't just echo it. You should consider to do:

```
foreach($userdata as $temp){
    echo $temp['image'];
}
```

And also, as others are saying remove all the leading html from your php file and just echo image name.

Answer (score 0):

Print your response with this line of JS:

```
console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Or you can also inspect your image tag `<img src="" />` with firebug and confirm whether you are getting the correct image name. If all is fine, check the file permissions of the user image folder and also the user image.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing username as string but getting variable using intval(). This will not work.